# Variable Fonts in SwiftUI to scale weight

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does Swift/SwiftUI support something like [Variable Fonts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_fonts/Variable_fonts_guide) for Web?

Currently my solution is to refer to the specific font files.
While it works, i have to embed a font for every weight. It would be more convenient if a single font could be "scaled" to any weight.

```swift
func myFont(size: CGFloat, weight: Font.Weight = .regular) -> some View {
    switch weight {
    case .regular:
        return font(.custom("MyFont-Regular", size: size))
    case .bold:
        return font(.custom("MyFont-Bold", size: size))
    default:
        assertionFailure("Font not available in given weight")
        return font(.custom("MyFont-Regular", size: size))
    }
}
```

```swift
// current
Text("Text")
    .myFont(size: 20, weight: .bold)

// desired
Text("Text")
    .myFont(size: 20)   // set the font
    .fontWeight(.bold)  // alter the weight
```

**EDIT:**
example of it not working as described in the answere:

[image: implementation example of font weight scaling]

Answer (score 0):

You can use .bold() with you custom font also like:

```
Text("Text")
   .myFont(size: 20)
   .bold()
```

EDIT:

You have to change function return to let it work

```
extension Text {
        func myFont(_ size: CGFloat) -> Text {
            self.font(.custom("YSText-Regular", size: size))
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work, if i use the regular font, the `.bold()` or `.fontWeight(.bold)` will have no effect

Comment: That works, tested with custom font. Change myFont return in Text. Code line in my comment.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. What Font did you use? Can you provide a minimal viable product? I'm happy to accept the answer if i can reproduce what you say

Comment: YSText-Regular, Montserrat-Regular

Comment: Example on top.

Comment: Added my implementation. What format is your font? Are there differences in that some scale and some don't?

Comment: Both are ttf, you can find them easy YSText on Google.
Check your info.plist file than you had added custom font properly too